# Why aren't the emails sent by my PHP contact form HTML formatted?

Tags: php, html, forms, html-email, contact-form

I am trying to make my own custom contact form. While testing it to make improvements, I found out the emails aren't coming in HTML format. I am not sure why this happens, but I figured out I must be doing something wrong, since my email service provider receives HTML formatted emails from other sources. I think the HTML code inside the message body variable is correct as well, so it must be something related to the headers variable or the way I set it.

EDIT: Unlike someone suggested, using style tags isn't my problem since I am not using Gmail (that doesn't accept them), but Outlook (that does accept them).

```
if ($_POST['Submit']) {
   if (empty($_POST['Phone'])) {
      $content = "<html>
          <head></head>
          <body>
            <div class='boldtext'>From:</div>
            $name
            <br/>
            <div class='boldtext'>E-mail:</div>
            $email
            <br/><br/>
            $message
           <style>
             .boldtext {
                font-weight: bold;
          }
          </style>
          </body>
        </html>";
   }
```

Above is part of my PHP code for the form action. The remaining part is some regex validations for each input and echos as response to those. The submissions are sent to an Outlook email address, which I know is compatible with the style tag in the head or body. What am I doing wrong?

Sample of email literally received by client:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
  <div class='boldtext'>From:</div>
  John Doe
  <br/>
  <div class='boldtext'>E-mail:</div>
  email@email.com
  <br/><br/>
  This is a message.
<style>
.boldtext {
font-weight: bold;
}
</style>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Inline styles aren't needed in this case. Outlook, not Gmail, will be the email service provider receiving these message submissions. "Use inline styles for everything. This site will convert your classes to inline styles: http://premailer.dialect.ca/" is definitely not the answer to my question.

Comment: When you say "not coming html format" do you mean the message received no html tags? Could you post what exactly the email client received from the php code?

Comment: Sure, just posted it. By "not coming HTML formatted", I mean that the variable $content, comes as it is, the format never gets to be read. I think the problem is in the header, or that I don't declare the email format properly. It's got to be that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out the reason the emails sent were not HTML formatted. It was not HTML or CSS related, The error was in the mail(); function:

The parameter $from interfered with $headers and did not let the HTML format work.

<del>mail($to, $subject, $message, $from, $headers);</del>

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

Everything works correctly now and the CSS structure depends on the email client compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

To best of my knowledge, you cannot add styles in a email like you have provided, but you can provide inline styles only to add styles in your emails. Do something like this example code,

```
<div style="font-weight:bold;">From:</div>
$name
<br/>
<div style="font-weight:bold;">E-mail:</div>
$email
<br/><br/>
<p style="font-weight:100;">$message</p>
```

edit: your code is this;

```
 if ($_POST['Submit']) {
   if (empty($_POST['Phone'])) {
      $content = "<html>
          <head></head>
          <body>
            <div class='boldtext'>From:</div>
            $name
            <br/>
            <div class='boldtext'>E-mail:</div>
            $email
            <br/><br/>
            $message
           <style>
             .boldtext {
                font-weight: bold;
          }
          </style>
          </body>
        </html>";
   }
}
```

you need to do like this,

```
 if ($_POST['Submit']) {
   if (empty($_POST['Phone'])) {
      $content = '<html>
          <head></head>
          <body>
            <div style="font-weight:bold;">From:</div>
            '.$name.'
            <br/>
            <div style="font-weight:bold;">E-mail:</div>
            '.$email.'
            <br/><br/>
            <p style="font-weight:100;">'.$message.'</p>
          </body>
        </html>';
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try this. I used the style tag, because this site https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/ says Outlook accepts it. I asked a similar question before which is unresolved and they advised me something similar to the code in my question.

Comment: Try as I have suggested, this might help you. :)

Comment: I did, it says: PHP Syntax Check: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'font' (T_STRING) in your code on line 14

Comment: Yup, literally tried this: if (empty($_POST['Phone'])) {
      $content = "<div style="font-weight: bold;">From:</div>
            $name
            <br/>
            <div style="font-weight: bold;">E-mail:</div>
            $email
            <br/><br/>
            $message";
   }

Comment: please see the answer, i have changed it accordingly, this time just copy paste it, the error won't be there anymore. :)

Comment: No issues found when analyzing the code, but the email is plain text, not HTML format, just like in the beginning. As I mentioned before, Outlook accepts style tags, so changing to inline style instead of CSS didn't solve the problem. The PHP are correct as before. The only problem is that the message comes through as plain text, not HTML formatted, and I don't know how to do that with headers or anything.

Comment: Are you using this in mail function, mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers)? Try adding more styles in the inline styles, this would give you more clearity if the inline code is working on not.

Comment: It comes like this: <html>
<head></head>
<body>
<div style="font-weight: bold;">From:</span>
John Doe
<br/>
<div style="font-weight: bold;">E-mail:</span>
email@email.com
<br/><br/>
This is a message.
</body>
</html>